# Accidentally removed own NTFS rights from volume in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, audio, permissions, ntfs

I am using Windows 7 and my hard drive is partitioned to C: and D: drives.
Yesterday I tried to limit some permissions for other users to volume D and accidentally denied everything for group "Users"

Now I can not access the drive even if I am administrator to the local computer. I did not touch the administrator permissions. I can not get to the Security tab of the volume because it says "Access denied".

How can I reset NTFS permissions or get my permissions back? Option is also, if possible, to backup my data to USB drive with some software and format the disk to start over.

I have tried:

- Booting to safe mode
- CMD: takeown /F D: /R
- Changed the drive letter to F: No use and reverted to D.

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score -2):

#### How can I reset NTFS permissions or get my permissions back?

This can be done in two different ways, using `TAKEOWN` or `ICALCS`.

1. Open an elevated command prompt (administrator).
2. Run the following command:

   ```
   takeown /F "d:\" /A /R /D Y
   ```

Or

3. Run the following command:

   ```
   icacls "d:\" /setowner "Administrators" /T /C
   ```

---

#### Further Reading

- [An A-Z Index of the Windows CMD command line](http://ss64.com/nt/) - An excellent reference for all things Windows cmd line related.
- [icacls](http://ss64.com/nt/icacls.html) - Change file and folder permissions - display or modify Access Control Lists (ACLs) for files and folders.
- [takeown](http://ss64.com/nt/takeown.html) - Take ownership of a file (Windows 2003/7/2008).

Comment: Tried these commands but did not work.

Comment: Both these commands do not work. I denied drive permissions using `icacls d:\ /t /c /deny everyone:F` and neither the `takeown` nor `icacls` commands in the answer work.